# im getting this message * file is encrypted or is not a database

Tags: ios, xcode, sqlite

please help me to see what's wrong in here? im getting a message *file is encrypted or is not a database. i already create a database in terminal named sampledb.sql. im just a newbie.

```
// Execute the query.
            int executeQueryResults = sqlite3_step(compiledStatement);
            if (executeQueryResults == SQLITE_DONE) {                    // Keep the affected rows.
                self.affectedRows = sqlite3_changes(sqlite3Database);

                // Keep the last inserted row ID.
                self.lastInsertedRowID = sqlite3_last_insert_rowid(sqlite3Database);
            }
            else {
                // If could not execute the query show the error message on the debugger.
                NSLog(@"DB Error: %s", sqlite3_errmsg(sqlite3Database));
            }
        }
    }
    else {
        // In the database cannot be opened then show the error message on the debugger.
        NSLog(@"%s", sqlite3_errmsg(sqlite3Database));
    }

    // Release the compiled statement from memory.
    sqlite3_finalize(compiledStatement);

}

// Close the database.
sqlite3_close(sqlite3Database);
}


#pragma mark - Public method implementation

-(NSArray *)loadDataFromDB:(NSString *)query{
// Run the query and indicate that is not executable.
// The query string is converted to a char* object.
[self runQuery:[query UTF8String] isQueryExecutable:NO];

// Returned the loaded results.
return (NSArray *)self.arrResults;
}


-(void)executeQuery:(NSString *)query{
// Run the query and indicate that is executable.
[self runQuery:[query UTF8String] isQueryExecutable:YES];
}
```

========================================================================

```
- (IBAction)saveInfo:(id)sender {
// Prepare the query string.
// If the recordIDToEdit property has value other than -1, then create     an update query. Otherwise create an insert query.
NSString *query;
if (self.recordIDToEdit == -1) {
    query = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"insert into peopleInfo values(null, '%@', '%@', %d)", self.txtFirstname.text, self.txtLastname.text, [self.txtAge.text intValue]];
}
else{
query = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"update peopleInfo set firstname='%@', lastname='%@', age=%d where peopleInfoID=%d", self.txtFirstname.text, self.txtLastname.text, self.txtAge.text.intValue, self.recordIDToEdit];
}

// Execute the query.
[self.dbManager executeQuery:query];

// If the query was successfully executed then pop the view controller.
if (self.dbManager.affectedRows != 0) {
    NSLog(@"Query was executed successfully. Affected rows = %d", self.dbManager.affectedRows);

    // Inform the delegate that the editing was finished.
    [self.delegate editingInfoWasFinished];

    // Pop the view controller.
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
else{
    NSLog(@"Could not execute the query.");
}
}

#pragma mark - Private method implementation

-(void)loadInfoToEdit{
// Create the query.
NSString *query = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"select * from peopleInfo where peopleInfoID=%d", self.recordIDToEdit];

// Load the relevant data.
NSArray *results = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:[self.dbManager loadDataFromDB:query]];

// Set the loaded data to the textfields.
self.txtFirstname.text = [[results objectAtIndex:0] objectAtIndex:[self.dbManager.arrColumnNames indexOfObject:@"firstname"]];
self.txtLastname.text = [[results objectAtIndex:0] objectAtIndex:[self.dbManager.arrColumnNames indexOfObject:@"lastname"]];
self.txtAge.text = [[results objectAtIndex:0] objectAtIndex:[self.dbManager.arrColumnNames indexOfObject:@"age"]];
```

}

Comment: No enough info. How did you create the db? Can you open the db using the sqlite commandline tool?

Comment: @zeFrenchy i use terminal to create db.

Comment: What command did you use? What does the resulting db file look like?

Comment: sqlite> CREATE TABLE peopleInfo(peopleInfoID integer primary key, firstname text, lastname text, age integer);
sqlite> .tables
peopleInfo
sqlite> .schema peopleInfo
CREATE TABLE peopleInfo(peopleInfoID integer primary key, firstname text, lastname text, age integer);
sqlite> .quit

Comment: Can you reopen the db file with sqlite once it has been created?

Comment: i cant. what should i do. when im trying to open the db file. this shows : There is no application set to open the document “sampledb.sql”.

Comment: At the terminal you must have typed "sqlite sampledb.sql" to create it right? What happen if you do that again? or what does the "file sampledb.sql" return?

Comment: @zeFrenchy here: 
sqlite3 sampledb.sql
SQLite version 3.8.10.2 2015-05-20 18:17:19
Enter ".help" for usage hints.
sqlite>

Comment: I'm starting to think you're winding me up. So is your table still there? ".tables" shows you your table?

Comment: yes it is. its stil here when i type .table  peopleInfo

Comment: Then your db file is fine, so that's good. but because you did not attach the actual db opening statement in your code, it's hard to tell you what you did wrong ... I recommend to read https://www.sqlite.org/capi3ref.html#sqlite3_open carefully

Comment: @zeFrenchy sorry if you think im winding you up. but its not. im just new here.

Comment: @zeFrenchy thank you so much for the help.